# Find intersecting set between two ranges

Tags: python, set

I have two sets given by boundaries.
For example:

```
set1_bounds = (1, 5)
set2_bounds = (2, 8)
```

Exactly real sets are:

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
set2 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```

Now for checking if these sets intersect, I create these sets using bounds and do following:

```
set1 = {i for i in range(set1_bounds[0], set1_bounds[1]+1)}
set2 = {i for i in range(set2_bounds[0], set2_bounds[2]+1)}
intersect = set.intersection(set1, set2)
```

But I think memory complexity (and computational too) is not the most optimal.

How should I do this correctly?

Comment: Why don't you calculate the intersection from the bounds themselves?

Comment: `if set1_bounds[1] > set2_bounds[0]`… (possibly sorting them first…)

Comment: @deceze ```if set1_bounds[1] >= set2_bounds[0] or set1_bounds[0] >= set2_bounds[1]```

Comment: `set1.insection(set2)` works little faster than `set.intersection(set1, set2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to generate both sets of ranges. Find the range of overlap, and generate a `set` from it:

```
r = max(set1_bounds[0], set2_bounds[0]), min(set1_bounds[1]+1, set2_bounds[1]+1)
set(range(*r))
# {2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Comment: nice, that's really cool, and works for all 6 different cases of interval overlap